# append command in middle of another file after first command and before last command

Tags: bash

i have 3 different files, the first file is a list that contains file paths.

```
/etc/home/hello.co.uk.pem    
/etc/home/stack.co.uk.pem
/etc/home/overflow.co.uk.pem
```

second file takes these paths and only gets the domain name, and places it into another command, which gets stored into the third file, the third file looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#after this command (this will be an actual command)

first domain: a.co.uk
second domain: b.co.uk
third domain: b.co.uk


#before this command (this will be an actual command, and must be at the end of the file)
```

at the moment it is appending underneath the last command, which i do not want, so how can i append the command after the other commands in the middle of the file and before the last command.

```
#before this command (this will be an actual command)

fourth domain: hello.co.uk.pem
fifth domain: stack.co.uk.pem
six domain: overflow.co.uk.pem
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: *"at the moment it is appending"* - can you show the code you're using?

Comment: Please don't make us guess what your code is. Copy/paste what you think is your best attempt into the body of the question and then use the `{}` tool from the **Edit** menu above the input/edit dialog so you get `code/data/output/errMsg` formatting. Good luck.

Comment: Your first file does not contain `a.co.uk` or `b.co.uk`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use SED to "inject" each line before a given marker in file #3.

Let's say this is file #3 (./file3):

```
This is line 01, blah blah
This is line 02, blah blah
This is line 03, blah blah
This is line 04, blah blah
#---inject-above---#
This is line 05, blah blah
This is line 06, blah blah
This is line 07, blah blah
This is line 08, blah blah
This is line 09, blah blah
This is line 10, blah blah
```

The injection marker is set as line `#---inject-above---#`.

Here's a short script illustrating how you can invoke SED to carry out the data injection (./inject.sh):

```
#! /bin/sh

TargetFile='./file3'

Marker='#---inject-above---#'

NewLine="${1:-blah blah blah}"

sed --posix -i -e "/^${Marker}\$/!b
i \\
${NewLine}"  "$TargetFile"
```

If you call the script twice like `./inject.sh 'blah blah blah'` and `./inject.sh 'a new line here'`, your target file should look like this:

```
This is line 01, blah blah
This is line 02, blah blah
This is line 03, blah blah
This is line 04, blah blah
blah blah blah
a new line here
#---inject-above---#
This is line 05, blah blah
This is line 06, blah blah
This is line 07, blah blah
This is line 08, blah blah
This is line 09, blah blah
This is line 10, blah blah
```

Does it help?